# Postfix and OpenSSL: "Unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate, openssl, tls

I bought a certicifate for my mail server and configured it in Postfix like so:

```
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /somepath/chain.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /somepath/myserver.key
```

I created `chain.crt` per [Postfix instructions](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_tls) by concatenating my certificate and the two intermediate CA certs. (To be precise, my own cert first, then `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt` and then `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt`) According to the logs, most connections to my mail server are now encrypted so everything seems to work.

However, when I connect to the server using `openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:25 -starttls smtp` I get the following output, which seems to indicate that something is wrong:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=mail.example.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
8<
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=mail.example.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5217 bytes and written 489 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: B2736D2B1639153CB8379480ACDBC1F0B1DCC51DE7CC27DA59061740F0186EA1
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 9EE658D6B1835F94D140E7BBF05A5A8960566584A8BC6FF40DD5D038C70127A63BAB580A41BC55DEEA3C031FCC7FA550
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 3600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 09 8a 6d 68 70 0c 64 c0-23 2e fc f2 d4 21 ca bd   ..mhp.d.#....!..
    0010 - 0a 15 4f 36 06 a8 ea f9-e2 84 de 18 cf 31 af 77   ..O6.........1.w
    0020 - 2a a1 98 d5 f8 df 54 48-82 68 cb c3 91 9b 38 60   *.....TH.h....8`
    0030 - dc 2e 18 f4 b9 bd 43 3e-26 cf 80 49 48 bb a4 98   ......C>&..IH...
    0040 - bc 94 7d 1e 5f 51 7e 52-d6 ad 7f 8b e5 36 ee 55   ..}._Q~R.....6.U
    0050 - 7a bb 15 d3 c2 7f b2 f4-5a 85 a5 80 1b 9e 67 98   z.......Z.....g.
    0060 - 3a 2f 5c d1 34 d5 bb 11-c7 8f fc 10 cb c3 b4 cb   :/\.4...........
    0070 - 49 61 41 ac aa b1 cb eb-6f 7a 22 e5 79 a2 c6 1f   IaA.....oz".y...
    0080 - 98 25 39 f0 f0 79 b4 ee-95 72 93 04 0f a2 f3 69   .%9..y...r.....i
    0090 - 8f 8a 86 c6 8f a5 38 ed-25 ba fc c8 db 6b 9a 8e   ......8.%....k..
    00a0 - 13 1e e5 c6 28 98 e4 17-ce 69 d5 c2 aa 1a de 4b   ....(....i.....K

    Compression: 1 (zlib compression)
    Start Time: 1400131328
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Also, when running `openssl verify chain.crt` I get the same error message:

```
chain.crt: OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = mail.example.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I have tried adding the `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt` to the end of `chain.crt` which makes the error message change to `verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain`. Besides, the machine I'm connecting from already has this certificate installed so there should be no need for it.

So my question is: Is there something wrong with my mailserver or am I just using the `openssl` command incorrectly? And should I include the root certificate in the chain or not?

Comment: Why not mail.example.com:465 or :995 ?

Comment: @schaiba 465 (smtps) is a depreciated SSL/TLS wrapped port for MUA->MSA communication, as such it won't help for general MTA->MTA communication. However, postfix doesn't treat the certificates any differently. 995 (pop3s) is not something postfix handles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've installed it correctly, but your verification step is incorrect. OpenSSL doesn't know where to look to find root certificates unless you explicitly tell it.

Try `openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:25 -starttls smtp -CApath /etc/ssl/certs` instead. That should work.